# HTML text field input -> site on my page

Tags: html

I have a problem with my HTML-Website.
I would like to have a text field which generates a link after entering and pressing a button from the input. For example, in the text field is "development" and by pressing the button should my browser go to "www.laurensk.at/development".
I don´t have the code for that...

Comment: HI @l-K,Please Read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've understood your question, you can do it using JQuery or Javascript

```
$("#btnGoto").click(function(){
   window.location="www.laurensk.at/"+$("#txtPage").val();
});
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `addEventListener`function to generate the link when there is a new input in the field.

Example:

```js
var path = document.getElementById("path")
var link = document.getElementById("link")

function makeLink() {
  link.href = "http://my.web.site/" + path.value
  link.innerHTML = "http://my.web.site/" + path.value
}

path.addEventListener("keyup", makeLink)
```

```html
<input id="path"/>
<br>
<a id="link" target="_blank"></a>
```

Documentation: [EventTarget.addEventListener() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)